# Is there a way to export Active Directory data into a data base or spreadsheet?

Tags: active-directory

I ultimately need to get the active directory user information into XML for use in another system, but using a database (SQL Server, or MSAccess, for example) or a spreadsheet or even .csv file would work for me.

Comment: You can use `csvde` or `ldifde` to export Active Directory user infos into a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could export everything with PowerShell to XML (or CSV, but it's limited).
It should be something like that:
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))" -SearchBase "DC=Contoso,DC=com" -SearchScope Subtree -Properties * | Export-Clixml -Path D:\Test.xml -NoClobber

But be careful, it would probably take a lot of resources from your DC.